# Using a single function between other pages

Tags: react-native

When I write code and I need to do something more than once I create everything dynamically. I use the same function on every page with a single reference.

I'm new to react so I'm truly trying to understand how to go about this, but I cant seem to figure it out.

So in javascript lets say I have 3 pages.

Page1

```
const EX_JS_GEN = require('./js/EX_JS_GEN.js');
var x = EX_JS_GEN (10, 12)
console.log(x)
```

page1

```
const EX_JS_GEN = require('./js/EX_JS_GEN.js');
var x = EX_JS_GEN (11, 11)
console.log(x)
```

external page

```
exports.EX_JS_GEN = function(x,y){return x * y}
```

I have tried storing the data, Ive tried things that I believe would work but most of it Isnt it either crashes or comes up with a warning.

so page 'worker.js'

```
enter code here
  exports.Something = function(x,y){
    var answer = x * y;
    return answer;
    }
```

now on any other page i should do the require first

```
 import Worker from '../js/Worker';
```

then I should be able to call the method

```
    var foo = Worker.Something (10, 120)
    console.log(foo)
```

Ive also tried using promises.

so page worker2.js

```
function intital(STRING) {
 return fetch('http://192.168.88.233:8081/'+ STRING, {
      method: 'POST'
     })
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((responseData) => {
      return responseData;
 })
 .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

then on any page.

```
    import Worker from '../js/Worker';
    Worker.intital().then(response => console.log("AUTH " + response));
```

so when I pass a value thru it use the function to calculate

I'm getting a crash, or undefined.

May be someone could give me a brief example so I could better understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try something like the following adapting the path and names as needed:

```
// Inside EX_JS_GEN.js
export const EX_JS_GEN = (x, y) => {
  return x * y;
}
```

Now, back to the other page where you'd want use it:

```
// Page1.js
import {EX_JS_GEN} from './js/EX_JS_GEN.js'
let multiple = EX_JS_GEN(10, 2);
console.warn('>', multiple);
```

Comment: thanks bud. seems small changes to your code makes things work. or breaks it lol.